# Error GXJMake: "Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection"

Tags: java, web, genexus

This error happens to me in `Genexus X Evo1, Generating Java for Web.`

When I try to compile **any** object, in the end it always returns the following error. I've noticed that the object is generated in the `Models` folder but not in the `WebApps.` I have tried the `Rebuild all` option and the same thing happens. I don't know what else to do.

```
========== Build With This Only started ==========
========== Target Environment update started ==========
Target Environment update Success
Building changed objects list
========== Specification started ==========
Generating messages for Spanish ...
Generating messages for English ...
Generators messages generated.
Specifying EnviarCorreoNoReply (1 of 1) ...
Specifying stub EnviarCorreoNoReply ...
Specification Success
========== Generation started ==========
Generating Resources...Success
Generating to DESARROLLO\web\aenviarcorreonoreply.java
Generating to DESARROLLO\web\enviarcorreonoreply.java
Generating to DESARROLLO\web\SdtMessages_Message.java
Generating to DESARROLLO\web\StructSdtMessages_Message.java
Generating to DESARROLLO\web\gxcfg.js
Generating to DESARROLLO\web\GXcfg.java
Generating to DESARROLLO\web\client.cfg
Generating to DESARROLLO\web\bld12.info
Generating to sm12_4.ari
Compressing static files...Success
Generation Success
File 'upload.jar' copied to "C:\Models\abc\DESARROLLO\web\drivers\upload.jar"
========== EnviarCorreoNoReply Compilation started ==========
callmake.bat "C:\Models\abc\DESARROLLO\web\GXJMake.exe" "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_45\bin\javac.exe" aenviarcorreonoreply options: -O
GeneXus Java Make v1.0
Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter Name: index
Build failed.
EnviarCorreoNoReply Compilation Failed
Build With This Only Failed
```

If I manually run the **GXJMake**, the same thing happens too:

```
C:\Models\abc\DESARROLLO\web>GXJMake -f home.mak
GeneXus Java Make v1.0
Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Build failed.
```

Comment: you shoud try http://es.stackoverflow.com/. Here it's expected you ask in english, read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

After I tried several things without luck, I was finally able to solve the problem.

What I did was to remove **all** of the **.ari** archives from the **C:\Models\abc\ folder and all of its subfolders**, not just the **C:\Models\abc\DESARROLLO\state** folder because I already tried that without luck.

I hope this is helpful if someone else encounters the same problem.